# Can I compress data in JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, compression

I'm using some pretty heavy AJAX with lots of data going from client to server. How can I compress the data (mostly plain text) before sending to the server?

And how can I uncompress the data on the server side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jSEND seems to do EXACTLY this. Anyone ever use it?

**Broken link removed: led to spam landing page @ jsend.org**

Comment: I'm having issues getting it to work though. So if you have any luck, please share.

Answer (score 1):

The [jsolait](http://jsolait.net/) library has [a codec](http://jsolait.net/browser/trunk/jsolait/lib/codecs.js) that supports the LZW algorithm (among others, including base64 encoding/decoding). The only thing that makes me a little hesitant is that this library is no longer being actively maintained.

**EDIT**

I was able to find [a](http://marklomas.net/ch-egg/articles/lzwjs.htm) [few](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression#JavaScript) [more](https://github.com/saw/JS_LZW) implementations of the LZW algorithm in Javascript.

Comment: `base64` increases the size of the data, not reducing it.

Comment: @Matt I was asking him to use LZW not `base64`. I was merely mentioning that the codec also supports other formats.

Comment: jsolait  link  is broken

Answer (score 0):

Using [LZW compression](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression#JavaScript):

client site:
http://jsfiddle.net/sebastienp/p7kDe/

server site:
http://webdevwonders.com/lzw-compression-and-decompression-with-javascript-and-php/